# R: gdal_translate/gdalwarp/gdalUtils for georreferencing raster

Tags: gdal, r, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, gdalutils

I am currently working on georreferencing a 530 X 587 .bmp file called `my_raster.bmp` with `gdal_translate` and `gdalwarp` from `gdalUtils` package, which is equivalent to using GDAL with those commands. This is the dataframe with the control points I am using for the georreferenciation:

```r
    pixelX    pixelY      mapX     mapY
1 236.2745 -226.4738 -75.59471 6.271575
2 231.4869 -242.2936 -75.59574 6.266845
3 275.4078 -254.5748 -75.57561 6.258759
4 271.3488 -261.3919 -75.57759 6.254840
5 264.8959 -274.8180 -75.58061 6.248533
6 219.6220 -270.6549 -75.60182 6.250831
```

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
gdal_translate("my_raster.bmp",
               "my_raster.tif",
               gcp = as.numeric(t(as.matrix(a[1, c(3:4, 1:2)]))),
               of="GTiff",
               verbose=TRUE)


gdalwarp("my_raster.tif",
         "my_raster_2.tif",
         r = "near",
         order = 1,
         co = "COMPRESS=NONE", 
         verbose = T, 
         overwrite = T)
```

---

When I execute the `gdal_translate` line, I get the following message, which I interpret as success:

```
Checking gdal_installation...
Scanning for GDAL installations...
Checking the gdalUtils_gdalPath option...
GDAL version 2.4.1
GDAL command being used: "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.8\bin\gdal_translate.exe" -gcp "-75.5947054422743" -gcp "6.27157506214069" -gcp "236.274468085106" -gcp "-226.473758865248" -gcp "-75.5957415423836" -gcp "6.26684503990253" -gcp "231.486879432624" -gcp "-242.293617021277" -gcp "-75.5756051619983" -gcp "6.2587589542668" -gcp "275.40780141844" -gcp "-254.574822695035" -gcp "-75.5775872665552" -gcp "6.25483979298375" -gcp "271.348758865248" -gcp "-261.391932624113" -gcp "-75.5806054712215" -gcp "6.2485330966662" -gcp "264.895921985816" -gcp "-274.817996453901" -gcp "-75.601822999547" -gcp "6.25083053603902" -gcp "219.621985815603" -gcp "-270.654875886525" -of "GTiff" "C:/my_raster.bmp" "C:/my_raster.tif"
Input file size is 530, 5870...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Nevertheless, when I execute the `gdalwarp` line, I get the following message:

```
Checking gdal_installation...
Scanning for GDAL installations...
Checking the gdalUtils_gdalPath option...
GDAL version 2.4.1
GDAL command being used: "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.8\bin\gdalwarp.exe" -overwrite  -order "1" -r "near" -of "GTiff" -co "COMPRESS=NONE"  "C:/my_raster2.tif"
NULL
Warning message:
In system(cmd, intern = TRUE) :
  running command '"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.8\bin\gdalwarp.exe" -overwrite  -order "1" -r "near" -of "GTiff" -co "COMPRESS=NONE"  "C:/my_raster2.tif"' had status 1
```

I am not able to georreference the raster

How can I do this using the aforementioned tools?

Comment: How were you not able to georeference it? Did the functions show an error? Or were there no errors but no sign that the image was georeferenced?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've just added the error messages I got when executing the code. Thanks!

Comment: Hello!

Please reopen, as @Spacedman's concerns about the clarity of the question have been addressed, or otherwise provide feedback about what's missing so as to add enough clarity to the question. :-)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Plus I've figured out the source of the problem. gdal_translate is only adding one GCP, but I dont think its possible to add more than one in R because the GCP parameter isn't treated as repeatable... One more reopen vote needed

Comment: @Spacedman: thanks for your insight and your endorsement on the reopening of the question! 

"Crazy" idea: maybe adding each GCP one by one?

Comment: I can't get that to work because gdal_translate is now quoting the four args to -gcp such that the command only sees one argument. Have emailed maintainer...

Comment: @Spacedman: in the meantime, I managed to solve my needs by calling GDAL via Windows shell (CMD) by means of the `system` function of the `base` package. Will follow up on this, though. Thanks!