# Georeferencing rasters using GCPs in R: stars/terra equivalent of gdal_translate / gdalwarp?

Tags: r, georeferencing, gdalwarp, terra, stars

With the retirement of rgdal and transition to sf/stars/terra functions in October 2023 now passed, is there a way of georeferencing raster images with GCPs (Ground Control Points) other than using library(`gdalUtils`)?

See [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342024/r-gdal-translate-gdalwarp-gdalutils-for-georreferencing-raster) for the `gdalUtils` approach.

1. As far as I know `terra` doesn't have a function to rotate or transform rasters using affine transformations
2. `stars` does have this option and recently added `st_geotransform` (details [here](https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/reference/st_geotransform.html)) to apply affine transformations but as of yet I haven't managed to correctly apply the length 6 numeric vector in the arguments, and using GCPs would be substantially easier.
3. `qgis`/`qgisprocess` libraries don't seem to run the `Georeferencer` function [available in QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/georeferencer.html)

Have I missed anything here? What current functions or approaches are available in R georeferencing with Ground Control Points?

Comment: can you please provide example data?

Comment: I was using `gdal_translate` and `gdalwarp` directly, like `system(paste("gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp ... ... ...", input_file, output_file))` and `system(paste("gdalwarp -r lanczos -tps -co COMPRESS=LZW  -t_srs EPSG:2180",  "input", "output")`